# How to set Dimm power capping value in OpenBMC

Tags: openbmc

I have an OpenBMC project and there has a problem.
There's a value is 0 which sensor name is "Dimm Power Cap C".
This sensor is generated by dbus-sensor(CPUSensor) package instead of using json file.
I can set CPU power capping value by BIOS but I can't set this sensor by BIOS.
How can I set or get this sensor value?

ipmitool sensor:
Dimm Power Cap C | 0.000  | Watts  | ok  | na   | na    | na    | na    | na    | na

busctl :
Service xyz.openbmc_project.CPUSensor:
`-/xyz` -/xyz/openbmc_project
|-/xyz/openbmc_project/inventory
| `-/xyz/openbmc_project/inventory/system |`   -/xyz/openbmc_project/inventory/system/chassis
|     `-/xyz/openbmc_project/inventory/system/chassis/motherboard |       |-/xyz/openbmc_project/inventory/system/chassis/motherboard/CPU_1 |       |-/xyz/openbmc_project/inventory/system/chassis/motherboard/CPU_1_mctp |`       -/xyz/openbmc_project/inventory/system/chassis/motherboard/CPU_2
`-/xyz/openbmc_project/sensors |-/xyz/openbmc_project/sensors/energy | |-/xyz/openbmc_project/sensors/energy/Cpu_Energy_CPU1 | |-/xyz/openbmc_project/sensors/energy/Cpu_Energy_CPU2 | |-/xyz/openbmc_project/sensors/energy/Dimm_Energy_CPU1 | |-/xyz/openbmc_project/sensors/energy/Dimm_Energy_CPU2 |` -/xyz/openbmc_project/sensors/energy/Platform_Energy_CPU1
|-/xyz/openbmc_project/sensors/power
| |-/xyz/openbmc_project/sensors/power/Cpu_Power_Average_CPU1
| |-/xyz/openbmc_project/sensors/power/Cpu_Power_Average_CPU2
| |-/xyz/openbmc_project/sensors/power/Cpu_Power_Cap_CPU1
| |-/xyz/openbmc_project/sensors/power/Cpu_Power_Cap_CPU2
| |-/xyz/openbmc_project/sensors/power/Dimm_Power_Average_CPU1
| |-/xyz/openbmc_project/sensors/power/Dimm_Power_Average_CPU2
| |-/xyz/openbmc_project/sensors/power/Dimm_Power_Cap_CPU1
| |-/xyz/openbmc_project/sensors/power/Dimm_Power_Cap_CPU2
| |-/xyz/openbmc_project/sensors/power/Platform_Power_Average_CPU1
| `-/xyz/openbmc_project/sensors/power/Platform_Power_Cap_CPU1

Thanks!